# Automatically Deploy Flutter Web Project to Firebase Hosting with Codemagic CI/CD

Tags: firebase, yaml, flutter-web, codemagic

How can I use CodeMagic.io to automatically deploy my Flutter web application builds to firebase hosting?

Currently the only options that appear to be supported are Codemagic Static Pages and Amazon S3 Buckets. Unless a custom build script is used.

I have done some research on the custom build script option and there is not much information online pertaining to automatically deploying to firebase hosting. Although I suspect you may be able to modify provided example in the Codemagic distribution documentation ('Publishing an app using Firebase CLI' [https://docs.codemagic.io/publishing-yaml/distribution/]) to achieve this. See code extract below.

```yaml
- name: Publish the app to Firebase App Distribution
  script: |
    apkPath=$(find build -name "*.apk" | head -1)

    if [[ -z ${apkPath} ]]
    then
      echo "No apks were found, skip publishing to Firebase App Distribution"
    else
      echo "Publishing $apkPath to Firebase App Distribution"
      firebase appdistribution:distribute --app <your_android_application_firebase_id> --groups <your_android_testers_group> $apkPath
    fi
```

Does anyone know how I can write a custom script that achieves the desired outcome?

Answer (score 3):

as per my e-mail

Firebase CLI is installed to Codemagic machines by default, thus like Mikhail said as well, you will have to add `FIREBASE_TOKEN` to your environment variables, please encrypt it first with Codemagic UI.

You can obtain the token by running `login:ci` in your local console. Then after the build step you will just have to run `firebase deploy --token "$FIREBASE_TOKEN"` (either in the post-build script in the UI, or add it to your .yaml) in the root of your project, where Codemagic is at by default.

Answer (score 1):

before deploy from CI/CD service ensure you completed following steps:

1. you have created firebase project via `firebase init`
2. you have added `firebase.json` to your repository
3. make sure you have firebase token (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#cli-ci-systems)

The next step is configuring CI/CD workflow

1. add `FIREBASE_TOKEN` to environment variables (check https://docs.codemagic.io/flutter/env-variables/ if you use Codemagic UI configuration)
2. add this script to your post-build script

```
#!/bin/sh

cd $FCI_BUILD_DIR
firebase deploy -m 'my comment'
```

Comment: can you elaborate more? cause this would mean that I would have to run the firebase init command in my project and commit the changes, store the firebase token on code magic and then somehow tell the firebase deploy command to use the web .zip artifact that is generated in the deployment process as opposed to the default which is the public folder.

Comment: hi, I've added more information, but had no chance to test it

Answer (score 0):

Following step by step [this guide](https://blog.codemagic.io/publishing-web-apps-to-firebase-hosting/) made me successfully configure the deployment on Firebase Hosting from Codemagic.

It's important to run the command firebase config in the root of your Flutter project (using `build/web` as a public directory) so that `firebase.json` and `.firebaserc` are created.